# How to Non-stop replication mysql server

Tags: mysql, database-replication

In the production environment, I have a master and slave,but for some reason

some synchronization data of the slave is not synchronized

so the error code 1032 is caused.

I saw the solution and use the command:

```
set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1;
```

Now that db cannot be shut down, what method can I use to repair my slave

The master will always insert, delete, and update operations, Can't stop.

slave is only used to read,and I can Truncate slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I encountered is composed of these:

1. The server cannot be shut down when I dump
2. If there is any operation to change the database, the index of binlog will change

How to solve this problem,

you can record the current position and index at the moment the dump.

```
mysqldump -u user -p mydb --set-gtid-purged=OFF --single-transaction --master-data=1> mydump.sql
```

> --master-data=1

Indicates that the current position and index are recorded when finish dump.

```
cat idn_maindb.sql |grep "MASTER_LOG_FILE"
```

And you will get the index and position.